# How I can put this in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello to all how I can put this in a function and after that call it:

```
  $(".submit").click(function(){
    var val_text_ = $('.submit_form input[name="Title"]').val();
    var val_body_ = $('.submit_form textarea').val();   
    var val_link_ = $('.submit_form input[name="Hyperlink"]').val();
    var val_link_description_ = $('.submit_form input[name="HyperlinkDescription"]').val();
    var val_date_time_ = $('.submit_form input[name="DateTime"]').val();
    var val_deliverables_ = $('.submit_form select[name="DropListValueDeliverables"]').val();   
    var val_groupvalue_ = $('.submit_form input[name="DropListMeasureGroupValue"]').val();
    var result_deliverables_ = result_of_option_.text();
    createListItem(siteUrl, val_text_, val_body_, val_date_time_, val_link_, val_link_description_, result_deliverables_);
 });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I personally have no idea what you're talking about....

Comment: Well, you can put any code you want into a function by simply defining a function and, well, putting the code there.  Aside from that... What are you actually asking?  What is *preventing* you from putting this in a function?

Comment: ...do you want to make a function that you call, which adds a listener to each `.submit` element? Or do you want to make a function that ***does*** the thing that happens, when a `.submit` element is clicked?

Comment: Norguard yes call on submit

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the javascript functions documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp).

But I believe this is the updated code in a function for you...

```
   function yourFunction() {
  $(".submit").click(function(){
    var val_text_ = $('.submit_form input[name="Title"]').val();
    var val_body_ = $('.submit_form textarea').val();   
    var val_link_ = $('.submit_form input[name="Hyperlink"]').val();
    var val_link_description_ = $('.submit_form input[name="HyperlinkDescription"]').val();
    var val_date_time_ = $('.submit_form input[name="DateTime"]').val();
    var val_deliverables_ = $('.submit_form select[name="DropListValueDeliverables"]').val();   
    var val_groupvalue_ = $('.submit_form input[name="DropListMeasureGroupValue"]').val();
    var result_deliverables_ = result_of_option_.text();
    createListItem(siteUrl, val_text_, val_body_, val_date_time_, val_link_, val_link_description_, result_deliverables_);
 });
}
```

Comment: you missed out how to call it

Comment: Thanks, i'll remember that in the future

Answer (score 1):

If you give your function a name you can call it independently whenever you want just by invoking it.

```
function foo(){
    var val_text_ = $('.submit_form input[name="Title"]').val();
    var val_body_ = $('.submit_form textarea').val();   
    var val_link_ = $('.submit_form input[name="Hyperlink"]').val();
    var val_link_description_ = $('.submit_form input[name="HyperlinkDescription"]').val();
    var val_date_time_ = $('.submit_form input[name="DateTime"]').val();
    var val_deliverables_ = $('.submit_form select[name="DropListValueDeliverables"]').val();   
    var val_groupvalue_ = $('.submit_form input[name="DropListMeasureGroupValue"]').val();
    var result_deliverables_ = result_of_option_.text();
    createListItem(siteUrl, val_text_, val_body_, val_date_time_, val_link_, val_link_description_, result_deliverables_);
 }
```

Once wrote this function will respond to the name of foo, just add the braces and calling it

```
foo();
```

If you need to you can also call it in other event's function body

```
$('#otherElement').keypress(function(){
   //Do your stuff

   foo();
};
```

Comment: Or $('#otherElement').click(foo());

Comment: @price you're right but it should be `$('#otherElement').click(foo);` -- with the `()` the function will be invoked immediately it's encountered.